# Как внедрять зависимости если в конструкторе указан интерфейс

Tags: php

Использую PHP DI, нужно подключить готовую библиотеку, но она в конструкторе требует интерфейс. подключаю так ка в доках написано.

```
return [
'ParamsInterface' => DI\create('FormParams'),

'HelperRequest' => function (ParamsInterface $params) {
    return new HelperRequest($params);
},
```

];

Но в моем случае "ParamsInterface" реализуют несколько классов как быть в таком случае, Может покажите где искать.

Comment: Может прокинуть конкретную реализацию?

Comment: Уважаемый а в чем у вас проблема то? в Том что библиотека использует интерфейс ParamsInterface и до подключения библиотеки вы написали свой ParamsInterface ???